# Is there a GetObjectType in DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using POCO proxies and I'd like to get the type of a object.  I've found a few [examples](http://www.coding4art.com/archive/2012/03/13/entity-framework-1-ndashhow-to-get-the-original-type-of.aspx) using GetObjectType for ObjectContext but I'm using DbContext and I don't see it there.  Is this something I need to add to my repository class so it can have access to the DbContext?  Or am I completely wrong?  Thanks

Comment: You can get ObjectContext from DbContext by using `((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContextInstance).ObjectContext`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a static method [ObjectContext.GetObjectType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn219922(v=vs.113).aspx) which, of course, you can use anywhere where `System.Data.Objects` is in scope. You don't need a `DbContext` instance.

Comment: Be careful if you've upgraded to EF6. It doesn't use System.Data.Entity.dll and you should remove references to it. The correct ObjectContext in EF6 is `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.GetObjectType(e.GetType())`. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767644/150342

Comment: For EF Version 5.0 System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetObjectType(typeof(DbContext)); - also put System.Data.Entity into references

Comment: That's for EF < 6. I updated the link to the EF6 method.