# ObjectContext.GetObjectType(e.GetType()) not returning the entity type of the POCO entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The [ObjectContext.GetObjectType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.getobjecttype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should return "the entity type of the POCO entity associated with a proxy object of a specified type"

So how come in my code it just returns the proxy?

I am using entity framework 6 release candidate

```
        //Soft delete
        var e = Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        e.IsDeleted = true;
        InsertOrUpdate(e);

        Type t = System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetObjectType(e.GetType());
        string name = t.Name;
        //Property_6C887DE7274181E6E99D6FCF2C21BDD59E226F99B0064F59954E70062C135331

        //Surely I shouldn't have to use Substring here?
        name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("_")).ToSpacedTitleCase();
        string message = name + " deleted";
```

Comment: What do you get when you invoke `ObjectContext.GetKnownProxyTypes()` after your first line?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using the wrong `ObjectContext`. EF6 is not built on System.Data.Entity.dll. You need to use `ObjectContext` from EntityFramework.dll. It's actually not recommended to have a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll in your project at all if you are using EF6 to avoid situation like this.

To fix your issue:

- remove the reference to System.Data.Entity.dll (just in case)
- replace `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetObjectType(e.GetType());` with `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.GetObjectType(e.GetType())`