# Get Table and Field Names for an Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for on SO or via google.

I'm setting up data auditing to track changes on specific entities via Entity Framework 5 (database first).  I am using a single log table, which will track changes at the field/column level.  I want to track the table name (not the entity name) and the column name (not the entity field name).

I have tried a number of things using the MetaDataWorkspace but can't quite seem to get the exact results I am looking for.  I am not including the metadata code, since none of it was really fruitful.  Note that one of the problems I have had is that my entity is actually a dynamic proxy at runtime.

Here is my current code:

```
IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry> entities =
        context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(
                e =>
                e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified);

bool auditingRequired = false;
var auditEntities = new List<AuditEntity>();


foreach (DbEntityEntry entity in entities)
{
    //IFullyAudited is a marker for the entities I want to track 
    if (!(entity.Entity is IFullyAudited)) continue;
    auditingRequired = true;

    //note that entity.Entity is actually a dynamic proxy here

    string tableName = ""; //how can I get the actual table name (not the entity name)

    //there would be different logic for adds and edits--this just covers edits
    foreach (string propertyName in entity.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
    {
        string columnName = "";  //how can I get the actual column name?

        var currentValue = entity.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);
        var originalValue = entity.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);

        if (!Equals(currentValue, originalValue))
        {
            //just a fake/POCO, not a real EF Entity until I figure this out
            auditEntities.Add(new AuditEntity
                {
                    //save PK here as well
                    ColumnName = columnName,
                    TableName = tableName,
                    NewValue = currentValue.ToString(),
                    OldValue = originalValue.ToString()
                });
        }
    }
}

if (auditingRequired)
{
    //here I will add the audit entity to the context
}
```

Comment: You can get the real entity by calling the static method `ObjectContext.GetObjectType` Just make sure you call the correct one for your version of entity framework. It changed in EF6 http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767644/150342